# Pass through exit status code after using ||

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit-status

I want to write an alias that's something like:

```
alias baz="false || echo bar"
```

(It's not actually `false`, it's a command that can fail). However, I want to pass the failed status code through to the next invoker. In other words, here's the current behavior:

```
$ false; echo $?
1
$ false || echo foo; echo $?
0
```

I want to do a different operation that has the same behavior in every respect as `false || echo foo`, except when I do `echo $?` it would return `1`.

*Note:* I expect the `echo foo` bit to essentially always succeed.

Comment: `false || echo foo && false`

Comment: Or at a certain level of not-`tcsh` complexity instead use a function, and save the return status and return it later on after other codes.

Comment: @Kusalananda of course. this is what i get for not eating my wheaties this morning. If you turn that into an answer I'll give you rep

Comment: `false || ( ret=$?; do_stuff; exit $ret )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function to save the return value of a command isn't that complicated:

```
f() {
    some-command-that-can-fail
    retval=$?
    if [ "$retval" != 0 ] ; then
         echo the command failed
    fi
    return $retval
}
```

If you don't care about the exact return value, but just want a nonzero return code, this would work:

```
somecmd || ( echo it failed ; false )
```

You need the subshell (or a compound block) to only run the final `false` if the original command fails.